# identify desktop file of application that appears multiple times

Tags: gnome, google-chrome, 18.04

I have an application that shows up multiple times with the same name and icon but one fails to launch and the other does not. It has happened for several different types of applications but the latest occurrence is the Google Hangouts extension(s). (*files below*)

How can you identify the desktop file associated with an application listed in the menu if the file is not named in a human-readable format? Is there some GUI tool that can give you the path to the icon when you mouse over or have a right-click content menu on the application?

I cannot simply read the contents of the file to understand which one is the correct file and which one is broken as another question/answer points out.

## Finding and opening via a file explorer

If I navigate to the folder to directly execute them, I get this[image]
Additionally in Gnome, Nemo will not show hidden files/folders to navigate to the path and you cannot enter the path directly.

## Desktop files

`cat /home/pcnate/.local/share/applications/chrome-knipolnnllmklapflnccelgolnpehhpl-Default.desktop`

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Name=Google Hangouts
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --profile-directory=Default --app-id=knipolnnllmklapflnccelgolnpehhpl
Icon=chrome-knipolnnllmklapflnccelgolnpehhpl-Default
StartupWMClass=crx_knipolnnllmklapflnccelgolnpehhpl
```

`cat /home/pcnate/.gnome/apps/chrome-knipolnnllmklapflnccelgolnpehhpl-Default.desktop`

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Name=Google Hangouts
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --profile-directory=Default --app-id=knipolnnllmklapflnccelgolnpehhpl
Icon=chrome-knipolnnllmklapflnccelgolnpehhpl-Default
StartupWMClass=crx_knipolnnllmklapflnccelgolnpehhpl
OnlyShowIn=Old;
```

Comment: Is your system a default Ubuntu 18.04 or have you installed some other desktop environment as well? I'm asking because you wrote: "Additionally in Gnome, **Nemo** will not show hidden files/folders to navigate to the path and you cannot enter the path directly."

Comment: Good point. It was a default 17.10 with gnome 3 installed using xorg. Then upgraded to 18.04 and switched to gnome 3 on Wayland

Comment: There's nothing sinister about those `.desktop` files. Google creates them. I don't know why. I have them for YouTube, GMail, Google Drive, and Google Docs. Since you haven't specified the applications other than Google's, I can't comment on those. Also, a link to "as another question/answer points out" may be helpful.

Comment: nothing sinister except having multiple from multiple profiles and no way to tell them apart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up manually searching for desktop files in the terminal and then renaming them so as to break the launcher icon. Once identified, I was able to delete it.

```
# export a list of all desktop files
sudo find / -name '*.desktop' > desktop_file_list

# read and grep each one looking for ( in this case ) 'Hangouts'
while read p; do if [ -f "$p" ] && grep -q Hangouts "$p" ; then echo "$p"; echo; cat "$p"; echo; echo; fi ; done < desktop_file_list

# rename
sudo mv /path/to/desktop/file.desktop /path/to/desktop/file.desktop.bak
```

Then try opening the program in the start menu or whichever manner. In my case, using Gnome 3, hit <kbd>super</kbd> and then type the name of the program.

If it is the wrong file, repeat the `sudo mv` command swapping .desktop with .desktop.bak